# How can I use a string from an array in one method in another?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have an array as shown below

```
private ArrayList<Blogs> parseJSONResponseCar(JSONArray response) {
    if (!response.equals("")) {
        try {
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentQuestions = response.getJSONObject(i);
                String Blue = currentQuestions.getString("text");
                String Yellow=currentQuestions.getString("id");
```

How can I extract the getString("id") value and put it in a new OnClick Listener method??

```
    public void OnUp (View view) {}
```

Comment: A little more claification please, what do you intend to do? You intend to use the String Yellow value in the void OnUP(View view) {} method?

Comment: Not sure to understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Your string Yelow is id string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a global class variable outside function like this:

```
string globalVar = "";
private ArrayList<Blogs> parseJSONResponseCar(JSONArray response) {
  String Yellow=currentQuestions.getString("id");
  globalVar = Yellow;
}

public void OnUp (View view) {
  string test = globalVar ;
}
```

If its a web application you can store in Session.